# Is $L^\infty$ compactly embedded in $L^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, lebesgue-measure, compact-operators

I'm trying to find a contraction example to show that the space $L^\infty$ is not compactly embedded in $L^1$ with the Lebesgue measure.

Please help me!

Comment: What's the domain of the functions? If we consider for example $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $L^1(\mathbb R)$, then $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is not a subset of $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Try the sequence $f_n(x)=\operatorname{sign}\sin (2^n \cdot 2\pi x)$.

Answer (score 2):

divide the interval [0,1] to N subintervals and take the function $F_N$ as below:

in odd subintervals equal 1

in even subintervals equal 0

Comment: Looks correct. So $F_N$ are bounded in $L^\infty$ norm and it contains no Cauchy subsequences in $L^1$ norm.